# Show number of Notifications on the side navigation menu

Tags: android, navigation, horizontalscrollview, spannablestring

I am using Horizontal ScrollView to get facebook like side navigation

Like this:

[image]

But how to show that "2" beside the Event item in the menu?

In my application i am using a ViewUtil class to get this menu:

```
public class ViewUtils {

    private ViewUtils() {

    }

    public static void setViewWidths(View view, View[] views) {
        int w = view.getWidth();
        int h = view.getHeight();
        for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
            View v = views[i];
            v.layout((i + 1) * w, 0, (i + 2) * w, h);
            printView("view[" + i + "]", v);
        }
    }

    public static void printView(String msg, View v) {
        System.out.println(msg + "=" + v);
        if (null == v) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("[" + v.getLeft());
        System.out.print(", " + v.getTop());
        System.out.print(", w=" + v.getWidth());
        System.out.println(", h=" + v.getHeight() + "]");
        System.out.println("mw=" + v.getMeasuredWidth() + ", mh="
                + v.getMeasuredHeight());
        System.out.println("scroll [" + v.getScrollX() + "," + v.getScrollY()
                + "]");
    }

    public static void initListView(Context context, ListView listView,
            String prefix, int numItems, int layout) {
        // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in
        // list.
        String[] arr = new String[numItems];
        arr[0] = "Feed";
        arr[1] = "Friends";
        arr[2] = "Notifications";
        arr[3] = "Feedback";
        arr[4] = "Logout";
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layout, arr));

    }
}
```

and set the adapter like this in the Activity:

```
    ViewUtils.initListView(this, myListView, "Menu ", 5,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

I what my "Notifications" Text to be something like "Notification       n" where n is like the "2" in the above pic. I tried to use Spannable String but i cannot set the Spannable String to the String Array "arr"

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming those categories (News Feed, Messages,...) are items of a `ListView`.
Also, for displaying that "2" I'm assuming you will need a custom adapter.

In this case you just need to add a `TextView` to your row XML file and set the appropriate value in the `getView()` method of your custom Adapter, or, if you are create the TextView programaticaly in the `getView()` method.